# How to plot data to map from csv file in D3.js

Tags: csv, d3.js

I'm trying to plot circles on top of a map using d3.js, I got most of the code working and can plot points from custom data, however when it comes to plotting them from csv the same code doesn't work

Here is the full code:

```js
// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

// The svg
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height"),
  overflow = 'hidden';

// Map and projection
var projection = d3.geoAitoff()
  .scale(width / (1.6 * Math.PI))
  .translate([width / 2 - 60, height / 2])

//Zoom the map
/*
svg.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
    svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}))
*/

svg.style("border", "10px");

// Load external data and boot
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson", function(data) {

  // Draw the map
  svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(data.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", "#737CA1")
    .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
      .projection(projection)
    )
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      div.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", .9);
      div.html(d.properties.name + "<br/>")
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      div.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("stroke", "#fff")
    })

})


var places = [{
    name: "EIM00003953",
    location: {
      latitude: 51.93,
      longitude: -10.24
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Newcastle, Australia",
    location: {
      latitude: -32.92669,
      longitude: 151.77892
    }
  }
]
//C:/Users/Cristian/Desktop/Advanced Infovis/Assignment2/
svg.selectAll(".pin")
  .data(places)
  .enter().append("circle", ".pin")
  .attr("r", 2)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + projection([
      d.location.longitude,
      d.location.latitude
    ]) + ")";
  });

places = d3.csv("/test.csv", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data[0].Longitude);
});

svg.selectAll(".pin")
  .data(places)
  .enter().append("circle", ".pin")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + projection([
      d.Longitude,
      d.Latitude
    ]) + ")";
  });
```

```css
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 28px;
  padding: 2px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  border: 10px;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>
<svg id="my_dataviz" width="1000" height="500" padding="0px"></svg>
```

The following plots custom defined points on top of the map (correctly):

```
var places = [
  {
    name: "EIM00003953",
    location: {
      latitude: 51.93,
      longitude: -10.24
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Newcastle, Australia",
    location: {
      latitude: -32.92669,
      longitude: 151.77892
    }
  }
]
//C:/Users/Cristian/Desktop/Advanced Infovis/Assignment2/
svg.selectAll(".pin")
  .data(places)
  .enter().append("circle", ".pin")
  .attr("r", 2)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + projection([
      d.location.longitude,
      d.location.latitude
    ]) + ")";
  });
```

However when I try to change it to get data from csv (the following code), I can't see any points showing:

```
  places = d3.csv("/test.csv",function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data[0].Longitude);
  });

  svg.selectAll(".pin")
  .data(places)
  .enter().append("circle", ".pin")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + projection([
      d.Longitude,
      d.Latitude
    ]) + ")";
  });
```

I already checked that the latitude and longitude values are correct, what is the issue?

Ps: Bonus question, how do I make the points show on top of the map? I tried both raise() and plotting them after the map has been drawn, however it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please add a file with some sample CSV points and host it somewhere, like on Github. Also, data read from a CSV file are always strings, so you should parse numbers as such by for example `+d.Latitude` or `Number(d.Latitude)`

Comment: You need to use your csv data in the callback function for d3.csv: `d3.csv("/test.csv", function(data) {   svg.selectAll(..).data(data)... });`

Comment: @Ruben Helsloot I'll post whole project on github then ;)

Comment: Sorry for the late relìply, I've had a lot of work to do. Thank you! I managed to plot them on the map based on your comments :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case you wondered I managed to fix the issues based on the comments in my question, here is the final code corrected

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    div.tooltip {   
        position: absolute;         
        text-align: center;         
        width: 60px;                    
        height: 28px;                   
        padding: 2px;               
        font: 12px sans-serif;      
        background: lightsteelblue; 
        border: 10px;
        border-color: black;
        border-radius: 8px;         
        pointer-events: none;           
    }
</style>

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Create an element where the map will take place -->

<svg id="my_dataviz" width="1000" height="500" padding = "0px"></svg>
<script>

// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

// The svg
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    overflow = 'hidden';

// Map and projection
var projection = d3.geoAitoff()
    .scale(width / (1.6*Math.PI))
    .translate([width / 2-60, height / 2])

//Zoom the map
/*
svg.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
    svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}))
*/

svg.style("border","10px");

// Load external data and boot
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson", function(data){


    // Draw the map
    svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter().append("path")
            .attr("fill", "#737CA1")
            .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
                .projection(projection)
            )
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div.html(d.properties.name+"<br/>")
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
                })                  
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
                div.transition()        
                    .duration(500)  
                .style("stroke", "#fff")
            })
            
})


 d3.csv("/test.csv",function(d) {
      console.log(d);
      svg.selectAll(".pin")
      .data(d)
      .enter()
      .append("circle", ".pin")
      .attr("r", 2)
      .raise()
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + projection([
          +d.Longitude,
          +d.Latitude
        ]) + ")";
      });

  });


</script>
```

I'll create a git project and put the link here once I get to it so you can test it with the data as well

Comment: [link](https://github.com/CristianLeoni/Weather_stations_visualization) to the Github project